# How to call a vue method from inside the xAxis.labels.formatter() highcharts object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts, frontend, vuejs3

So what i am trying to achieve is that, there should be a checkbox before the value in the xAxis and it should call my `test()` vue method when the checkbox is changed by clicking on it. Right now it is calling `test()` when buildChart() method is called.

```
buildChart() {
      const context = this;
      return {
        chart: {
          height: 500,
          type: 'columnrange',
          inverted: true,
          spacingLeft: 10,
          spacingRight: 10,
        },
        xAxis: {
        showEmpty: false,
        title: null,
        type: 'category',
          labels: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter() {
              // This is where i am rendering the checkbox, would like it to trigger my vue function which is within the current vue context.
              return `<input type='checkbox' onchange='${context.test(this.value)}'> ${this.value}`;
            },
          },
        },
     };
}
test(value) {
console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, returned value from a `formatter` function is treated as a string.

As a solution, you can store a label's value in a `data-*` attribute and add `change` event after the chart is created.

```
export default {
  methods: {
    test(value) {
      console.log(value); 
    }
  },
  data() {
    const context = this;
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          events: {
            load: function() {
              const labelGroup = this.xAxis[0].labelGroup;
              const checkboxes = labelGroup.div.getElementsByTagName('input');
              
              for (const checkbox of checkboxes) {
                checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(e){
                  context.test(this.dataset.value);
                })
              }
            }
          }
        },
        xAxis: {
          showEmpty: false,
          title: null,
          type: 'category', 
          labels: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter() {
              return `<input type='checkbox' data-value=${this.value}> ${this.value}`;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }
};
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-fork-j4ty16?file=/src/components/Chart.vue